# 3 step POST form. Use sessions, hidden fields or...?

Tags: php, forms, session, post

I'm putting together a 4 step registration form, which at the end will redirect the user to Paypal and enter the entire form contents into the database.

At present I have the following flow:

Page 1 - Enter Details
Click Submit (POST)

Page 2 - Check page 1 Details
Page 2 - Put details into $_SESSION
Page 2 - Enter more details
Click Submit (POST)

Page 3 - Check page 2 details
Page 3 - Put details into $_SESSION
Page 3 - Enter more details
Click Submit (POST)

Page 4 - Check page 3 details
Page 4 - Process all data and put into DB
Page 4 - Redirect to Paypal
Page 4 - Listen for success before setting flag to active in db
DONE

My question is, am I going about this the right way? Although it works fine I've had to use jquery hacks to enable users to go 'back' at any stage to make changes to the form.

I was considering using hidden fields instead of SESSIONS so that each step would resubmit all of the data, and I could back-POST all data to a previous page if the user wanted to go back a step. I think there might be more chance of the user loosing their data this way though?

Comment: I prefer Session than hidden fields as it is more secure and clean

Comment: Just a bump. Did you find any good solution? I'm thinking about maybe doing a function that echos all previous post-fields as hidden in a form automatically to make it easier to manage if more fields are added (can be made for the session stuff aswell) because I have an "optional step" which is a login screen if not logged in it can use the same POST-handling weather or not logged in.

Answer (score 2):

Hidden fields concept will make things difficult to manage...in case if the number of fields are more.

Its better to use session in your case instead hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

It depends : do you have the need to do a POST after each step ? If not, you could aswell just put all steps in your page, each in a fieldset, and display only 1 fieldset at a time in javascript (as you're talking of jQuery). This way only the submit button on the last step would submit the whole form

On the other hand, if you need to have a post after each step, I would choose the session approach, which is more secure

Comment: I think my limited knowledge of jquery is what has stopped me putting the form all on one page. Main reason being that page 2 shows a formatted preview of page 1 and a lot of the functions I've written to format the data I have no idea how to code in JQuery.